# PHP Sagepay iframe integration

Tags: php, iframe, integration, opayo

I want to make my website payments via sagepay. The problem is I am not able to locate all the things in the PHPKit they provide. The version of the kit is 3.0 and I want to configure iframe integration but when I open the test method there is this piece of code

```
$view = new HelperView('server/low_profile');
        $view->setData(array(
            'env' => $this->sagepayConfig->getEnv(),
            'vendorName' => $this->sagepayConfig->getVendorName(),
            'integrationType' => $this->integrationType,
            'request' => HelperCommon::getStore('txData'),
        ));
        $view->render();
```

I want to locate those keys **'env', 'vendorName', 'integrationType', 'requests'** and see how to put them to use in my system. I see this syntax in a lo of places

```
public function setSagepayConfig(SagepaySettings $sagepayConfig)
    {
        $this->sagepayConfig = $sagepayConfig;
    }
```

But I don't know what SagepaySettings means and how to trace it. Can you tell me where can I find SagepaySettings, or what does this mean. Is it a class or method or attribute, because I cannot find it in all the files as any of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a class in `\lib\classes\settings.php`